# How to Support SSO on custom web server application using NTLM?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, ntlm, jaas

I have custom web server application java based. I would like to support Single-Sign-On authentication to my Domain Active Directory using NTLM.

What is the best way to implement it?
Can I accomplished that using JAAS only?

All information that I read point to use Kerberos/SPNEGO but I don't want to use that because my Domain Controller is configured to work with NTLM, and most of my clients are using the NTLM protocols in their domains.

If there is a way to support in my java code both of the protocols NTLM and Kerberos I will be glad to know.

Comment: Have you founded answer for this?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment... Unfortunately no. I kind of put it aside since this mission got low priority. If someone will post an answer I'll be glad to receive.